# How to build staging env constants using grunt-ng-constant?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am trying to inject environtment constants into my `yo angular` generated angular application using grunt-ng-constant. Apart from development and production, I have one more environment called 'staging' where I will host my built dist folder.

From what I followed on most of the blogs, we run `ngconstant:development` while running `grunt serve` and `ngconstant:production` while doing a `grunt build`. So, is there a way to differentiate production env from staging while running build. Can I pass arguments to this task?

Comment: A workaround would be to register a new task 'build-staging' similar to 'build' but invoke ngconstant:staging. Would love to know if there is a clean way to do it.